# Cloud Functions for Firebase database onWrite triggered twice

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

Hi I am developing a notification system, but I am having trouble deleting the processed notification data. The `onWrite` event listener is triggered twice resulting to two notifications.

Can you help me find a work around so that onWrite event listener should not be triggered twice? It is important to delete the processed data.

```
exports.sendMessageNotification = functions.database.ref('/notification/message/{recipientUid}/{senderUid}').onWrite(event => {
/* processing notification and sends FCM */

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
      // For each message check if there was an error.
      const toRemove = [];
      response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
          console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
          // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
          if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
              error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
            toRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
          }
        }
      });

      //Deletes processed notification
      console.log("Removing notification");
      const getNotificationPromise = admin.database().ref(`/notification/message/${recipientUid}/${senderUid}`).once('value');
      return Promise.all([getNotificationPromise]).then(results => {
        const notificationSnapshot = results[0];
        toRemove.push(notificationSnapshot.ref.remove());

        console.log("Removing tokens.")
        return Promise.all(toRemove);
      });
      //return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
    });
});

})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common mistake.  You are writing back into the same database location (by removing the data) that was matched when the function first triggered.  This means that removal will be triggering the function again to handle that second change.  This is currently the expected behavior.

You will need to come up with a way to detect that the second write happened in response to the removal of data.  Also, you are currently doing too much work in your function.  There's no need to read the value of the database at `'/notification/message/{recipientUid}/{senderUid}'` - it is already being delivered to you in the event that's passed to the function.  Be sure to [read the docs about database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data).  You can know if the function was triggered a second time by examining the event data and returning early if it's null, which means it was removed.

Also, you don't need Promise.all() if you are dealing with a single promise.  Just use then() on that single promise to continue processing, or return that single promise from then().

You might want to look at some of the [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) that shows database triggers.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it really helped me understand the triggers especially the event object.

Comment: This answer helped me learned that I can get the data snapshot through `const data = event.data;` and add an if inside the function and return if there's no value `if(data == undefined || !data.val()){return;} `

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is still confused about this, **as of [firebase-functions v0.5.9](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases) ; you can use onCreate(), onUpdate() or onDelete().** Just make sure your firebase-functions version is updated which you can do so by going in your functions directory and run

```
npm install --save firebase-functions
```

Also, it has been addressed in firebase documentation and [sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/index.js#L54-L61) as well that if you are using onWrite(), as Doug has explained above, the function will be triggered for all events at that node, i.e, write; update or delete. So you should check to make sure your function doesn't get stuck in a loop. Something like:

```
   //if data is not new 
    if (event.data.previous.exists()) {return}
    // Exit when the data is deleted; needed cuz after deleting the node this function runs once more.
    if (!event.data.exists()) {return}
```

Cheers.

Comment: In Android, I am using push to create a new node and get its key, and after that I use setValue. The `onCreate` event is fired for the push and the `event.data` is null? :(

Comment: Hmm.. Not sure what's the problem ; would need more info or possibly code to be more helpful but I have functions running with onCreate() and it's working fine. Perhaps make it a Q in SO and link it here and I could look at it

Comment: Sorry I was thinking that the push fires the `onCreate` event. But it is called only when we set a value to the new key.

Comment: Yes, as long as you have not written anything to db nothing would be called. You could initiate the process if that's what you want by pushing the generated key with a bool value or something just to write it to db and trigger the function for instance. Cheers