# Firebase Cloud Function not letting me delete a database object

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am simply deleting a user rooted at /users/{some-userid}

Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var adminApp = admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.userRoleChange = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/role').onWrite(event => {
  const parentRef = event.data.ref.parent;
  return parentRef.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
    if (snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    }
  });
});
```

and here is the log

[image]

Another interesting thing I can see from logs is it is getting triggered **twice**.

I think getting triggered twice is fine as it gets recreated so once for deletion and once for creation but I don't understand why it is getting recreated in the first place.

> Functions let you handle database events at two levels of specificity;
> you can listen for specifically for only creation, update, or deletion
> events, or you can listen for any change of any kind to a path. Cloud
> Functions supports these event handlers for Realtime Database:
>
> onWrite(), which triggers when data is created, destroyed, or changed
> in the Realtime Database.
>
> onCreate(), which triggers when new data is
> created in the Realtime Database.
>
> onUpdate(), which triggers when data
> is updated in the Realtime Database.
>
> onDelete(), which triggers when
> data is deleted from the Realtime Database.

Comment: onWrite() is triggered by deleting the data. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131416/cloud-functions-for-firebase-database-onwrite-triggered-twice

Comment: It should occur if we write back to same location , does using `parentRef.once('value')` inside callback write it back ?

Comment: As I understand it deleting a value causes onWrite() to fire. I don't think you can avoid this, but you can check if the previous value was there and then you can just return if it's not. The question I linked to has an answer that gives an example of this. You can also look at my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427263/how-to-prevent-conflicting-firebase-cloud-functions/46429047#46429047